# Output 22 lines previously read - Java

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist

I am trying to read from a file, and when a blank line is read , it will output the line 22 lines prior to the blank line. Example, if program read all line up the first blank line at line 44, then it will print the 22nd line.

Currently i have it working so that it reads and stores input into an arrayList and then outputs it. I am wondering what the most efficient way of doing this is? I also am trying to make sure that no more than 23 lines are ever stored at once. Is arraylist the appropriate data structure for this?

```
public static void test(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();

    String line;
    int n = 0;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        s.add(line);
        n++;
    }
    Iterator<String> i = s.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        w.println(i.next());
    }
}
```

thanks for any advice/input

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `String[]` of size 22 and perform the inserts and the "get" modulo 22.
Your code should looks something like this:

```
public static void test(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {

    String[] prev22 = new String[22];
    String line;
    int n = 0;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        prev22[n % 22] = line;
        if(line.trim() == null){
            w.println(prev22[n-22 % 22]);
        }
        else{
            w.println(line);
        }
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any data structure i could use for this?

Comment: @choloboy you don't need any special data structure for this, a simple string array of length 22 will do the trick.

Comment: Any kind of circular array data structure is enough. Most current answers show a quick implementation. There are also implementations online e.g. http://www.museful.net/2012/software-development/circulararraylist-for-java

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is a bit of an overkill. Since you know exactly the total number of lines you can use a String array.

However, you will have to keep information about what is the current "start pointer" (if you want to keep the order and use it in an effective circular fashion.

**Example: Using a custom circular array**

```
 public class CircularStringArray {

    private int currenInsertIndex = 0;

    private String[] array = new String[22];

    public void addString(String element)
    {
        array[currenInsertIndex++] = element;
        currenInsertIndex = currenInsertIndex % array.length;
    }   

    public String printStrings()
    {
        String result = "";
        for(int i=currenInsertIndex; i<array.length; i++)
        result+=i+")"+array[i]+"\n";

        for(int i=0; i<currenInsertIndex; i++)
        result+=i+")"+array[i]+"\n";

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        CircularStringArray test = new CircularStringArray();
        for (int i=0; i<50; i++)
        test.addString(new String(new char[]{(char)i}));

        System.out.println(test.printStrings());            
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not to use this `% SIZE` logic for `printStrings()` method as well.??

Comment: Good point.. though I suspect in terms of efficiency this is more efficient since using the modulo would incur an additional cost oer loop.

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList will store all the lines, till the blank. You can use a **Queue** of Strings of size 22. The *enqueue* and *dequeue* operations of queue takes constant O(1) time, and memory usage will also be minimal

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
public static void test(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {

   String[] s = new String[22];

   String line;
   int n = 0;
   while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
       s[n] = line;
        //This will take n to 0 when n is 21 i.e. last array position
       n = (n+1) % 22;
   }
   int last = n;

   //Will print it in the same order in which those lines were read.
   do{
         w.println(s[n]);
         n = (n+1) % 22;
     } while(n != last);
}
```

Comment: is there a data structure that i could use?

Comment: Why you want to use a nes data structure if existing DS solves it efficiently.